# Double commander icon does not show up

Tags: installed-programs

I have installed Double Commander (it shows in the software center as installed). Starter however does not show it and I cannot open it. During the installation it flashed very short in the programs on the left side. What is wrong?
My Ubuntu is 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing `doublecmd-common` and there wasn't any shortcut in the menus created, I did get these files installed:

```
$ ll /usr/bin/dou*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 26 Jan 30  2014 /usr/bin/doublecmd -> ../lib/doublecmd/doublecmd

$ ll /usr/lib/doublecmd/
total 24
lrwxrwxrwx 1   25 Jan 30  2014 doc -> ../../share/doublecmd/doc
-rw-r--r-- 1 6517 Jul 10  2011 doublecmd.ext.example
-rw-r--r-- 1 3966 Apr 10  2012 doublecmd.xml
lrwxrwxrwx 1   30 Jan 30  2014 language -> ../../share/doublecmd/language
-rw-r--r-- 1 5000 Jun  8  2013 multiarc.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1   29 Jan 30  2014 pixmaps -> ../../share/doublecmd/pixmaps
-rw-r--r-- 1  439 Aug 19  2012 pixmaps.txt
```

There is no /usr/lib/doublecmd/doublecmd , so nothing runs.

I'll try installing `doublecmd-gtk`... now

```
$ ll /usr/lib/doublecmd/
total 9124
lrwxrwxrwx 1      25 Jan 30  2014 doc -> ../../share/doublecmd/doc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 9317564 Jan 30  2014 doublecmd
-rw-r--r-- 1    6517 Jul 10  2011 doublecmd.ext.example
-rw-r--r-- 1    3966 Apr 10  2012 doublecmd.xml
lrwxrwxrwx 1      30 Jan 30  2014 language -> ../../share/doublecmd/language
-rw-r--r-- 1    5000 Jun  8  2013 multiarc.ini
lrwxrwxrwx 1      29 Jan 30  2014 pixmaps -> ../../share/doublecmd/pixmaps
-rw-r--r-- 1     439 Aug 19  2012 pixmaps.txt
drwxr-xr-x 7     140 Dec 18 12:19 plugins
```

Now there is an executable file and a shortcut, the program runs. Did you install the right packages?

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the apparent fact that what you are attempting to install is classified as BETA SOFTWARE (never a good idea), I can't speak for what may be wrong with the failed installation you were trying to make, but I could make a suggestion or four to ensure success if all you want is a file manager that works in a nearly identical fashion.

As a old-timey classic DOS user who very much appreciated the release of [Norton Commander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_Commander) in the late 1980's, I was thrilled to hear there were several nearly identical two-panel file managers for Linux.  You can find not less than FOUR of them in the UBUNTU SOFTWARE CENTER.

Until reading your post today, I had only installed "[gnome commander](http://gcmd.github.io/)" which I had installed on this system as I had been using it the longest, but after looking at the features of another one called "[Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/)" I installed that one just now because it looks like it might even be better.  The other two file managers to be found in the software center are called "Tux Commander" and "Krusader".

Generally speaking, you can be assured of easy installation and fully certified functionality by sticking to the software available to you in the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/software-center/), although I will admit that sometimes I need to install something it doesn't offer, such as the proprietary software for my Withings smart scale or the aftermarket software to operate my brother label printer.

Is there a particular reason you are choosing to install a mere file manager it doesn't offer?  What is it about "[Double Commander](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-double-commander-0-5-10-beta-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-pinguy-os-and-elementary-os-systems/)" you find so necessary?  I read about it and I don't understand the appeal outside of the unavoidable similarity of function to the Norton Commander.

Mostly I use the file manager included with Ubuntu because I teach Ubuntu and I prefer to be fluent in what my students are using.  I suspect I could make them all commander converts without much difficulty.

As I see you are a newbie on this site and as such may be unfamiliar with the GUI software center, I'll give you the quickstart to installing software using it:

1. Press the windows key on your keyboard.  (if your keyboard does not have one, click the icon in the upper left corner which functions like a finder)
2. Type "soft" (sans quotes), followed immediately by pressing enter.
3. WAIT for the software center to fully load be fore pressing more keys
4. Type "commander" (sans quotes) but do not press anything after that.
5. Read through the first few hits, not all of which will be file managers, but most will.  Pay attention to star ratings.  Read the descriptions to discover which ones best suit your needs.  None will occupy much space on your drive so consider installing all of them and determining by means of use which one is most satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with double commander for GTK2 and I solved it when installed double commander for QT4) More information is here- https://sourceforge.net/p/doublecmd/wiki/Download/

Comment: That link does not give more information. Can you expand your answer?

Answer (score 0):

For me Ubuntu 20.04 MATE
doublecmd-qt has not displayed shortcut in start menu. But running fine from bash terminal.
installing doublecmd-gtk fixed this. It displayed in the menu and become searchable.